# Adding Paragraph Spacing in Longtables

Tags: longtable

I am trying to add spacing between paragraphs inside the cells of a longtable. I don't want to spread out every line, just the paragraphs, just like regular paragraphs in my document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}    
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{51 pt}|p{370 pt}|}
        \textsc{Aug 2017}&\Large{{Sample Project Title}}\\
        \textsc{\hfill -Present}&Shortly before my start at Somewhere Industries, a catastrophic failure of one of the system conveyor occurred.

        I also drove the inventory management, document management and SAP system re-implementation to ensure all site-specific technical aspects were adequately addressed and integrated with asset management system and strategic initiatives.
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

(BTW: I don't want to use columns. The longtable format works best for what I need. I also don't want to learn a new environment. I like longtable :) )

A workaround I've found is using parskip INSIDE the cell as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}    
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{51 pt}|p{370 pt}|}
        \textsc{Aug 2017}&\Large{{Sample Project Title}}\\
        \textsc{\hfill -Present}&{\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}Shortly before my start at Somewhere Industries, a catastrophic failure of one of the system conveyor occurred.

        I also drove the inventory management, document management and SAP system re-implementation to ensure all site-specific technical aspects were adequately addressed and integrated with asset management system and strategic initiatives.
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

But I'd like it to a global setting.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that `\Large`, unlike `\textsc`, doesn't take an argument but acts as a switch, changing every text inside the current group (but since table cells form a group it doesn't do any harm here). Instead of `\Large{text}` you should use `{\Large text}`, inside table cells you can leave out the braces completely.

Comment: Can you please provide a small but complete example document that shows how you changed the paragraph spacing outside of `longtable` and what you tried to make those changes in `longtable`?

Comment: I've updated the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array package to inject code in every cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{longtable,array}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{51 pt}|>{\setlength\parskip{1ex}}p{370 pt}|}
        \textsc{Aug 2017}&\Large Sample Project Title \\
        \textsc{\hfill -Present}&Shortly before my start at Somewhere Industries, a catastrophic failure of one of the system conveyor occurred.

        I also drove the inventory management, document management and SAP system re-implementation to ensure all site-specific technical aspects were adequately addressed and integrated with asset management system and strategic initiatives.
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]